# Javascript string as closure function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I am generating Highcharts JSON using server-side technology like PHP.

From Browser I am sending an AJAX request to fetch complete Highcharts JSON and then rendering it.

for e.g MY AJAX Response is

```
    [
   {
      "plotOptions":{
         "enabled":false,
         "series":{
            "stacking":"",
            "point":{
               "events":{
                  "click":"function(e){console.log(e.point.config); console.log(e.point.category)}"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "chart":{
         "type":"column",
         "renderTo":"leftTopContainer",
         "polar":false
      },
      "series":[
         {
            "name":"netpos",
            "data":[6700,8200,11500]
         }
      ],
      "title":{
         "text":"Future Financial Commitments-5Y Yr View"
      },
      "xAxis":{
         "categories":["2010","2011","2012"]
      }
   }
];
```

**After getting server side response I'm rendering it Using following code**

```
new Highcharts.Chart(responseData);
```

**Everything is working fine except events**

```
    "events":{
    "click":"function(e){console.log(e.point.config); console.log(e.point.category)}"
               }
```

As you can see in JSON Response I am getting function in double quotes(" "),

**My Problems are**

1. Since this is a string I cannot call as function.
2. If I remove (" ") in PHP then jQuery Ajax Throws an error as "Invalid JSON or Parse Error"
3. I am not Allowed to use eval() as this is not a good programming practice.

IS there a way so that I can iterate over JSON object and convert string in to function so that it will be called automatically.

Comment: is there any particular reason you aren't just binding the event handler within your JS code?

Comment: pass javascript code in JSON is not a good programming practice too

Comment: @Alnitak We are building Server side chart creation and we  have written all events handling functions in a XML file. We are reading event data from XML and generating JSON.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is `eval()` so use it. You want to execute unknown code sent from the server. No matter what approach you try, at the end you do the same as `eval()` would do.

If you are sure, that code you sent is okay, there's no harm in using it.

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` is what you want, it's really the only way.

Why are you not allowed to use it? It's not as evil as it's portrayed, it's fine in this case. If you use a workaround you'll essentially be re-writing `eval()`.

Comment: this is not an answer, it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON you cannot add function definition but look at: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/json-schema/7f5Wd5yRluo maybe it will be helpful.